# What's the right site for questions about etymological relations of words from 2 or more languages?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope, languages

What will be the most appropriate site to ask questions like that:

[Is English 'issue' etymologically related to Russian 'ищу'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96047/is-english-issue-etymologically-related-to-russian)

I was suggested, that **English.SE** isn't the best site for such questions, because they are regarding meanings in other languages (in that case, Russian). I don't think that it will be more appropriate on **Russian.SE** since it is more question about English than Russian. I was informed that such questions are rather off-topic on **Linguistics.SE**. The **Languages** proposal is in definition phase on Area51 and doesn't seem to be very popular...

So, if I'm particularly interested in finding relations (common ancestry) between words in various languages, where should I ask them? Should I try, as in that case, to ask on one of the language's SE (if existing) or I should restrain and wait for something like **Languages.SE** or **Etymology.SE** to be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may not quite understand your confusion...

If you're interested in the etymology of "issue", ask on English.SE.

If you're interested in the etymology of "ищу", ask on Russian.SE.

If you're interested in *both*, then you have two questions - so ask both of them.

If you're interested in something else, and suspect that a shared etymology is the answer to *that*, then you have [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - figure out what X is, and ask that.